# geojson-vt with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

Does anyone have an example of a barebone repo of a react-leaflet project using geojson-vt?

I have react-leaflet project that has a 13 MB geoJSON file. I can't figure out how to get it to render faster with react-leaflet's geojson tag. I am hoping geojson-vt is the answer.

Comment: Do you have an example of a vanilla leaflet map that uses geojson-vt?  If you have that, we can adapt it for react-leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * @file Component to render geojson as vector tile with `geojson-vt`.
 * @name GeoJSONVtLayer.js
 */
import L from "leaflet";
import {
  createTileLayerComponent,
  updateGridLayer,
  withPane,
} from "@react-leaflet/core";
import geojsonvt from "geojson-vt";
window.geojsonvt = geojsonvt;
// eslint-disable-next-line import/first
import {} from "leaflet-geojson-vt";

export const GeoJSONVtLayer = createTileLayerComponent(function createGridLayer(
  { geoJSON, ...options },
  context
) {
  return {
    instance: L.gridLayer.geoJson(geoJSON, withPane(options, context)),
    context
  };
},
updateGridLayer);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/geojson-vt-with-react-leaflet-s43w8?file=/GeoJSONVtLayer.js)

Comment: demo's link is break